# Cookie based authentication doesnt allow access of https secure cookies when working with switching between MVC and single page application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, https, cross-domain, single-page-application

We are following cookie based authentication in the SPA and we have the concept of switching from MVC (OLD SITE) to SPA (NEW SITE) ie: A single sign on concept.

**Note:** In SPA the navigations are completely built using cookies - Angular 1.5 code.

Everything worked fine when in development and staging which was HTTP. But after release to production which runs as HTTPS on a secure SSL certification, we are not able to read the cookies from the spa that was set by MVC, hence switching is not successful.

Could you suggest what are we missing here, or any quick fix that can do be done so we can access the HTTPS secure  cookies and easily redirect them to dashboard in SPA.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sure halfer thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is not with cookie being secure, your issue is with cookie being set to 'http only' thus not accessible with client side code (angular). Removing http only from cookie is a quick fix though i would never recommend having auth cookie read from client side code for security reason.

Comment: so what is the other solution then , could you tell me what is the standard approach followed, cause in a way we do need cookies to swicth between mvc to spa and obviously we cant remove http-only from the cookies as it exploits xss vulnerability

Comment: What are the data you are reading from cookies ? if you are not reading the auth cookie then its ok to remove http only for those cookies (UI cookies)

Comment: we are actually reading username and password. which i know is completely wrong , but i want to know in what way we can optimize it?

Comment: You dont need to read the username and password or the authentication cookie, the cookie is automatically sent with the http request you send from the SPA page provided your SPA pages share the same cookie with old MVC. (hosted under same app pool)

Comment: im trying it other way round, where cookie is comming from MVC, and yes its comming over https , but we are not able to read it in SPA which always says undefined even when it is set under the same subdomain.

Comment: Dont attempt to read the cookie on client side. Instead, send an http request to the server and you will get the data you need. The request will be authorized since the cookie will be sent from the browser with each SPA http request. Stop trying to read the cookie, change the way.

Comment: sorry i dont understand here , the http request actually takes username and password to log him in and since i dont have the form but i am allowing the user to move from old to new , we are passing the credentials to SPA where we can send that to http , to send we have to read it , isnt it?  please let me know if im missing somethign here

Comment: Since both old mvc and new SPA lives under the same domain, you dont need to do all that. You just send an http request from SPA and the server code will treat it as if it is coming from old mvc. This is the power of cookie, they are sent with each http request implicitly without coding on client side.

Comment: Oh i nerver knew that. just for my clarity , i want to mention that the two sites are running on same sub domain , EG: abc.company.com and xyz.company.com  but are hosted at different places. so does ur solution still  fit in? and http cookeis will be passed to the api as parameter without even reading them?

Comment: So you have 2 host A records, each pointing to different server ip address. The session created on server 1 will not be available on server 2 thus authentication will not work unless you choose to store your session data in a shared storage like database. This is another story now.